# WPF Expander Header Mouseover color change

Tags: wpf, header, mouseover, expander

I have wpf Expander control and I want change background color of Header when I do mouse over on it.
Here is my control:

```
<Expander Margin="0" ExpandDirection="Right">
    <Expander.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Image Source="placeholder_imageObject.png"  Stretch="Uniform" Margin="6,0,0,0" Width="36" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <ContentPresenter Content="Image" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            <Path Data="{StaticResource RightArrowGeometry}" Fill="Black"  Margin="14,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            </Path>
        </StackPanel>
    </Expander.Header>
    <Grid Margin="10,0,0,0" Background="White">
        <controls:SymbolController x:Name="dgSymbolControl">
        </controls:SymbolController>
    </Grid>
</Expander>
```

Pls Help
thanks
Sai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can give your StackPanel within in your "Expander.Header" an Style with Trigger like this:

```
 <Style x:Key="MyCustomStackPanelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```